# I installed Visual Studio 2019 now the problem is I am not getting UI or Windows form options in Visual C++

Tags: user-interface, visual-c++, visual-studio-2019

I downloaded Microsoft Visual Studio 2019 recently and wanted to create a simple Windows app with a Windows form and some buttons with programming done on c++ so I installed all the c++ development support including c++/cli support even after doing it nothing came up as like a UI option under project>add item>under Visual C++ I am still having the same problem from where I will add Windows form and buttons..

I already read some answers although they were answered for Visual Studio 2017 I tried them like downloading c++/cli support and all nothing worked still having the same problems

Comment: You decide if you want a GUI or console application in the new project wizard (i.e. when you create the project).

Comment: The setting can also be changed later (it is in project properties). A project can be both: start with a console app and then add the references for WinForms/WPF... or start with a GUI app and use P/Invoke to call `AllocConsole`.

Comment: i usually start with windows form... as i am aware that console form is basically cui driven so i open  project as windows app project